# PrimeFaces extension javascript uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '1' of null

Tags: jsf, primefaces, ckeditor

I am using primefaces extensions as I need to use ckEditor.

I am getting my form lockup after an initial submit, and the the drop down lists are either being displayed incorrectly (about 1mm wide!) or are not selectable.

The only only new content I have introduced is primefaces extensions.

I see in Chrome editor I am getting this error below.

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '1' of null
>   PrimeFacesExt.getPrimeFacesExtensionsVersion
>   PrimeFacesExt.getPrimeFacesExtensionsCompressedResource
>   PrimeFacesExt.widget.CKEditor.PrimeFaces.widget.BaseWidget.extend.init
>   f.(anonymous function) primefaces.js.jsf?ln=primefaces:1 d
>   primefaces.js.jsf?ln=primefaces:1 PrimeFacesExt.initWidget
>   PrimeFacesExt.createWidget PrimeFacesExt.cw (anonymous function) bZ
>   b7.fireWith bG.extend.ready

My pom entries are below

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.primefaces.extensions</groupId>
            <artifactId>primefaces-extensions</artifactId>
            <version>0.7.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.primefaces.extensions</groupId>
            <artifactId>resources-ckeditor</artifactId>
            <version>0.7.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.primefaces.extensions</groupId>
            <artifactId>resources-codemirror</artifactId>
            <version>0.7.1</version>
        </dependency>
```

my namespace is:

xmlns:pe="http://primefaces.org/ui/extensions"

and my ckEditor is set up as below.

I have 3 of the editors in the page on different forms.

```
<pe:ckEditor id="emailEditor"  value="#{customerTasksBean.email.messageText}" width="800" height="400"
                        rendered="#{customerTasksBean.emailActive}" widgetVar="emailEditorVar" 
                        toolbar="[['Styles','TextColor', 'Format','Font', 'FontSize','-', 'Cut','Copy','Paste',
                                'PasteText','PasteFromWord','-', 'SpellChecker', 'Scayt' , '-',
                                'NumberedList','BulletedList', 'JustifyLeft','JustifyCenter','JustifyRight', 'JustifyBlock',
                                '-', 'Table']]"/>
```

the ckEditor is working beautifully, but there seems to be an issue on an initial persist of my form which breaks the page unless I refresh....

I am not sure if this javascript error is linked to the issue, but would be good to know I have at least got my extensions set up correctly.

i

Comment: Are you using a custom `<resource-handler>` in your webapp?

Comment: @BalusC not as far as I can see in faces-config

Comment: If I change my main submit button to be non-Ajax I do not get my p:selectOneMenu problems...I may have to go with that for now.  Not sure if it is actually related to the converters somehow, but the converters look good.

Comment: Hi,  I have 3 ckEditors in sepearate forms, within seperate tabs - some of which are not rendered initially.  Could this be the issue?  The javascript error goes away if I do a hard refresh of the page?